# Why can't an inner class create instances of itself without referring to the outerclass in python

Tags: python, scope, nested-class

To get some order in my code I put one class inside another, the inner class does not need the outer class at all (at least that was what I thought before).

The behaviour as code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=10
    def do(self):
        print(self.a)
        return A()
a=A()
print(a.do())
#this runs as expected with the output:
#10
#<__main__.A object at 0x01234567>

#cleaning up
del A

class B:
    #same code for class A
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.a=10
        def do(self):
            print(self.a)
            return A()
a=B.A()
print(a.do())
#This raises for the line 'return A()' a NameError: global name 'A' is not defined
```

I can't understand why A is not accessible from within itself in this case.

Here another thing that is similar and running fine:

```
def f():
    a=10
    class C:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def do(self):
            print(a)
            return C()
    return C().do()
print(f())
```

Additional question: Why do classes behave different to function in this case, what is the benefit we get out of this?

Comment: You're confusing functions and classes. classes are different from functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class variable is accessible unqualified only from directly within the class body.

When a variable name is looked up, the process works [this way](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/executionmodel.html) (assuming no `global` or `nonlocal` declarations):

1. Look in the current scope (class or function or global)
2. if not found, look recursively in the outer enclosing *function* scope
3. if not found, look in the global scope
4. if not found, look in the built-in scope

During the execution of a block, whether it is a function definition or a class body, the object itself does not exist yet, so obviously you cannot refer to it.

Let's see what might happen if classes are counted for enclosing scope in the binding algorithm:

```
x=3
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        A.x = 5

    def foo(self):
        print(x)

a=A()
a.foo()
```

There's no binding for `A.x` in the class definition, so `print(x)` must refer to the global x, right? But when `a.foo()` is called, there *is* an `A.x` to refer to. It's not intuitive. Function scope is immutable (inaccessible, in fact), unlike class scope.

In addition, you will need `classvar` statement, in addition to `global` and `nonlocal`. and it will only work for the *current* class, so you'll need `nonlocal classvar` statement as well...

I think another reason that classes are not counted as "enclosing scope" is to allow [class creation customization](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) using metaclasses. But I am not sure,

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
return B.A()
```

As class `A` is not a global variable it's an attribute of class `B`. Classes are namespaces in themselves, i.e all objects defined inside a class actually become it's attribute.

```
class B:
    #same code for class A
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.a=10
        def do(self):
            print(self.a)
            return B.A()

>>> B.A
<class __main__.A at 0x9f3ea1c>
>>> a = B.A()
>>> print(a.do())
10
<__main__.A instance at 0x9fd7aec>
```

code 2:

```
def f():
    a=10
    class C:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def do(self):
            print(a)
            return C()
    return C().do()
print(f())
```

This code is totally different,from nested class one. Functions don't create a new namespace, they just create a new scope.

So, class `C` is just a local variable to function `f()`, That's why calling `return C()` inside `do()` is going to work fine.

Tutorial :

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: What benefit do we get out of this behaviour?

Comment: You are returning instance of `A`, without running the constructor twice. (`B.A()` runs the constructor an extra time).

Comment: @Akavall Actually I wanted to point out the namespace thing to OP; that's why used that.

Comment: shouldn't >>> B.A be __main__.B.A?

Comment: @schwer All top-level variables in an interactive prompt fall under `__main__` module, `__main__` is never used that way. Please read the tutorials that I've linked in the answer.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I read (specially 9.2 of) the classes tutorial. There are multiple scopes (all of them implemented as dictionaries). I don't see why there is no scope for classes.

Comment: @schwer Because it won't allow for class creation customization.

Comment: @Elazar what is "class creation customization"?

Comment: @schwer [metaclasses](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)

Comment: "I don't see why there is no scope for classes" - there is. It just don't count as an *enclosing* scope.